# Extracting cell size of Raster as value for buffering using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, modelbuilder, buffer

I am creating a model in ArcGIS ModelBuilder to buffer a line. I would like the buffer distance to be based on the cell size of a raster. The cell size may change depending upon which raster the user decides to use.

Is there a way to extract the value of cell size so that it can be used to populate the buffer distance field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple model can achieve this as shown below.

[image: Model]

Note the output of the get raster property was connected to the Buffer tool using the Connect tool. Usually you would do an in-line substitution but that does not seem to work for some reason, but a manual connect does...

Answer (score 1):

In ArcMap 10.3 I've found that Buffer won't take CELLSIZE. It can be connected using the Connect tool, but then the model doesn't run.

However, using the Model Builder Calculate Value element as an intermediary works.

The Calculate Value expression can be something like %CELLSIZE%, referring to the Cellsize property obtained by Get Raster Properties. The calculated value can then be linked in to Buffer using Connect.

Comment: Where did you find *Calculate Value* tool? I have a hard time finding it using *Search* pane.

Comment: Found it! Right click anywhere on empty space and look for *Model Only Tools*.